# Write .properties file with coldfusion

Tags: java, properties, coldfusion

Does anybody already made this?
Because it is possible to use the JavaRB.cfc made by mr. Paul Hastings, but it gives the possibility to read from a properties file, no to write into it?

Answer (score 13):

You can use the underlying Java Properties class to do this pretty easily:

```
<cfscript>
fos = CreateObject("java","java.io.FileOutputStream").init(ExpandPath("out.properties"));
props = CreateObject("java","java.util.Properties");

props.setProperty("site","stackoverflow.com");
props.setProperty("for","Stephane");

props.store(fos,"This is a properties file saved from CF");
</cfscript>
```

Although the format of a properties file is pretty simple, so you could also use the ColdFusion file functions to write a properties file:

```
<cfscript>
props={"site"="stackoverflow.com","for"="Stephane"};
crlf=chr(13) & chr(10);

propFile = FileOpen(ExpandPath("out2.properties"),"write");
FileWrite(propFile,"##This is a properties file saved from CF" & crlf );
for(prop in props){
    FileWrite(propFile,prop & "=" & props[prop] & crlf);
}
FileClose(propFile);
</cfscript>
```

It probably comes down to where you have the data stored. If it's in a struct, it may be easier to use CF. If it's in a Java Properties object, then the code above is pretty minimal

Answer (score 0):

Should anybody stumble across this page in the future, I've also found how to read properties from [this source](https://cflib.org/udf/readPropertiesFile).

The comment from fishwhisprerer states as following:

```
Using Java in this scenario could be more efficient:

#myproperties
key=value

<cfscript>
props = createObject("java","java.util.Properties");
inputStream = createObject("java","java.io.FileInputStream").init(expandPath("my.properties"));
props.load(inputStream);
</cfscript>

Then anywhere below this:

props.getProperty("key")
```